# Unity sidebar window dodge Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, unity, window

I have found some solution to make the unity sidebar dodge windows, but none of them are working for Ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone have an idea how I can make the unity sidebar doge windows in Ubuntu 16.04?

EDIT: With windows dodge, I mean it would automatically hide itself when a window hits the sidebar. Pretty much like the Window Dodge setting of docky or cairo-dock for example.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "dodge windows" ? Can you explain the desired behavior in more details ?

Comment: @Serg I added a small description

Comment: Very interesting question. I think I can write a script for something like this. I'll need some time to work on it though. Maybe 3 - 4 days

Comment: That would be awesome! If you do write the script, please let me now :) Thanks bro

Comment: If you're still interested, I know of a modified version of the old script that works well on 18.04.